# What are these variables?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, syntax

I know that probably this question may get some negative points because of its specificity and it may sound stupid. But I'm pretty new to the syntax of Python and I'm not even sure if "variables" is even part of the answer. So please, be calm :)

I'm looking at [this Repository](https://github.com/wintershammer/QImp/blob/master/src/mini.py) on Github.

Here I saw some weird things at some lines (e.g. `57`, `89` etc.).
**The author put some *underscores* and after them some *commas*. Although I don't know what do they mean**:

```
_, _, param1, params, _, _, expr, _ , app = node
```

As much as I know a syntax to put multiple variables would be:

```
var1, var2 ,var3 = 1, 2, "3"
```

But at this point I don't know what to expect since simple underscores aren't considered variables especially when they are used multiple times (or are they ?) and the syntax in the git repository doesn't follow the rule above.

I searched some syntax cheat-sheets for Python but this doesn't match anything. So I would like the help of some of you.
Thanks

-- My Experience is limited to C/C++/C#/Java/Javascript [...]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_` is generally used as an identifier name when you want to indicate that you don't plan on using value produced. In Pythons REPL (Read-Eval Loop) it has additional semantics (of storing the last value produced) but that isn't the case here.

You are allowed to use multiple names while unpacking, that's what's the author is doing. The value for `_` will be constantly overwritten to (finally) hold the last value assigned. This value (the value corresponding to the rightmost `_` in the left hand side) is again indicated as something the author isn't really planning on using.

Of course, he could slightly trim it down to:

```
*_, param1, params, _, _, expr, _ , app = node
```

if he'd like to, where `*_` here is grabbing the first two values (previously written as `_, _, param1, ...`) and throwing them away.

Comment: Oh I see ... so asterisk symbolizes an underscore with a comma on its own ? (Thank you by the way)

Comment: Hm, didn't explain that much @general656. The `*` before a name in the right hand side of an assignment statement catches any excess values produced. For example, if `l = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and you only want to keep the last value, you could do `*_, last = l` and have `last` equal `4` and `_` grab the rest of the items `1, 2, 3` here in a list (and, since `_` it the name you chose you indicate that you really don't plan on using them).

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard I believe you mean on the left hand side

Comment: @Code-Apprentice ah! I can't even edit now! Right you are.